# Whenever i scroll the image, elevate zoom scrolls with it. How can i fix its position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a image wrapped in a scroll. below is a screeshot.
[image]

I've used elevate zoom js to zoom into the image while hovering on it. below is a screenshot

[image]

But the problem occurs when scrolling the image. the elevate zoom also keeps scrolling along with image. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

I wanted to know to how to fix the postion to the scrolling window itself using some jquery.